# Photoelectric effect and frequency

Tags: electric-current, conservation-laws, photoelectric-effect

Give an isolated photo tube and with a small emmiter and very large collector (no electron escapes)

As one increase the frequency, one is also increasing the kinetic energy of photo-electrons and that translates to a net charge flowing at a faster rate, which will infact increase the current. So increase in frequency correspond to increase in current.

Since $$T=(mv^2)/2 \implies v \propto \sqrt{T}$$ and $$T\propto \nu \implies v\propto \sqrt{\nu}$$

Current $I\propto -Nev$ where $e$ is charge of electron and $N$ is number of electron.

So $I \propto \sqrt{\nu}$

Inside the phototube the current is proportional to the frequency, since it is in linear connection with the circuit that current should add to the circuit given the continuity equation.

My question is why we consider that all frequency given the same no. Of photons will produce same current and isn't it violating (K.C.L) and equation of continuity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out the photocurrent do depends on the frequency and this is due to continuity

[image: Photo electric effect]

But this the case only when there is no other potential source or a source of energy that gives the electrons more energy, at saturation the potential itself energies the electrons so much greater than the energy provided by photon that it becomes irrelevant (or become negligible compared to potential difference). Even if photo-electrons start with no energy it will gain a lot of energy. So all the photon needs to do is just eject an electron given a large potential.

But if one is making a photo-cell one would want a higher frequency light to fall on it.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\phi$ be the number of photons per unit time per unit area ($\text{Hz/m}^2$) incident on the cathode. We are assuming the photon energy is greater than the metal work function, so each photon causes a photoelectron to be ejected. For simplicity, suppose also that each photoelectron is ejected in the same direction (toward the anode) with speed $v$.

Consider an area $\Delta A$ of the cathode illuminated for a time interval $\Delta t$. The electrons ejected at the beginning of the interval will have traveled a distance of $v \Delta t$, so the electrons ejected during this interval will occupy a volume of $\Delta A(v\Delta t)$. The number of electrons in this volume can be found using the average density $N$ of electrons moving toward the anode, and also using the photon flux $\phi$:

$$N\Delta A (v\Delta t)=\phi \Delta A \Delta t$$
$$Nv=\phi$$

As a result, given a fixed photon flux, $N$ and $v$ are inversely proportional and the photocurrent ($\propto Nv$) does not depend on $v$ or $\nu$.

A detailed calculation is not actually necessary. Suppose you are throwing pebbles at the sea at a rate of 1 pebble/minute. How many pebbles fall into the sea per minute? Does it depend on how fast (meaning how hard, not how often) you throw the pebbles?

Comment: The pebbles would have made sense if their was a source and sink in case of current in a circuit, but due to continuity the current of photocathode must be equal to the current in circuit and for a constant photo flux I am bound to have more energetic or faster electrons i.e. current in photo tube is gonna be more compared to low frequency same photon flux.

Comment: I don't understand what you think is the difference. The pebbles are conserved in the same way as electrons. The rate of pebbles you throw is equal to the rate of pebbles landing in the sea. Increasing photon energy is analogous to imparting more kinetic energy into the pebbles. Yes, higher photon energy means faster electrons, nothing I said is inconsistent with that.

Comment: The photoelectric current depends on frequency, I think you are talking just about the saturation current.